# Google SpreadSheet download csv with backslash for escape

Tags: google-sheets, escaping

When i download some Sheet of Google SpreadSheet, i get a file with commas for fields, and double quotes for escape special character.

Is it always like that?

Can i change double quotes

```
""
```

to backslash?

```
\"
```

Comment: Can you provide your current script? I think that it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: I mean use controls from menu FILE, i dont want use some script

Comment: I thought that your issue was related to your script. I'm sorry I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Well, after looking for an answer, I must say that there is none.
Google does not give the option to change the escape format.

An alternative that I applied was prior to downloading the file, is to replace
 
    " // double quote 

with 

    ' //  single quote  


In this way, i get a file with caracter like "' (for escape single quote), after that you can deal with OpenOffice or Excel.

Anothe way is write some code that can dump to file text ...